# What "union dispute" was Maz Kanata fighting?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In what was probably one of the *strangest* scenes in the film, we witness Maz (who for whatever reason was added in) inform our Trio of Heroes, <s>Lando</s> Finn, <s>Han</s> Poe and <s>Leia</s> Rose, about the

> Master Codebreaker who will have to get them onto the Supremacy in her stead.

While talking to them, she seems to be flying around in a battle which she calls a

> "union dispute"

Do we know what union dispute Maz was fighting? Could they possibly have any relevance with the clans that Solo got in a fight with back in TFA?

Does any additional source material or interviews give us insight into this?

Comment: Probably had something to do with the noodle incident.

Comment: How is Finn a substitute for Lando? What qualities does Finn exhibit that Lando did? What about the other two pairings?

Comment: @HorusKol I was just making a joke about it being an "ESB" duplicate. I came to the conclusion by pairing the two highly skilled pilots and the two female side-kicks. That left Finn and Lando. Make what you will of that pairing, and judge me as you please. I meant no harm or foul and I don't think the question portrays that either. If you disagree and feel offended or if anyone else does, I'll happily remove it from the question body.

Comment: @Edlothiad Seems like a natural parallel to me.

Comment: I am ready to be refuted, but it seemed obvious to me that she said something completely irrelevant to her real predicament not to give explanations she didn't intend to, just like she had said “Sorry for the noise, the plumber is fixing the faucet”.

Comment: One of the strangest scenes? Nah. Maybe we didn't want to know from where the blue milk was procured.

Comment: @RudyB I found that scene quite funny.

Comment: It was green milk. Blue milk is from Banthas

Answer (score 3):

We're not meant to know.

Life goes on. The galaxy is large. So it goes. We get an insight into the fact that there are other dramatic things going on in the galaxy over the course of the war, (which may be directly related to that war, indirectly related, or may have no connection at all) while the movie is focusing on few narrative strands.

As such the lack of an answer here is the very point of the scene.

Of course, later films *could* fill in the blanks, and novelisations almost certainly will, but conveying that Maz is the protagonist of her own interesting story that we don't know anything about is done by showing us that there is some interesting story happening but not telling us anything about it.